# use variable in other variable

Tags: php, variables, include

Hi in my mail I get a Text from a variable (`$text`) and sent it via `mail()`. In the text I want to use an other variable. I get it from my database. (`$text1`).

My text in the mail (inside the variable `$text`) looks like that.

"Hi `$text1`, how are you?"

Now I want to replace the `$text1` with the original text from the database.

What I must do?

For example:

```
$text1 = $row['text1'] // from Database1

$text2 = $row['text2'] // from Database1

$text = $row['text'] // from Database2
```

The content from `$text` is "Hi `$text1`, how are you? What do your dog `$text2`...."

```
mail('user@example.com', 'subject', $text);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code... Can't help much with what you've given us thus far.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: ok I add it. i hope it will help.

Comment: If I am understanding what you are wanting to do correctly, you can do it with eval.  See the php man page, I think the first example is quite similar to your problem.

[php.net - eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

This is pretty nasty though, if possible, I would come up with some slightly nicer.  Also, you need to make sure you fully trust what comes out the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$allVars = array('text1'=>'some text', 'text2'=>'some other text');
```

UPD: in your case, $allVars is $row array from database.

```
foreach($allVars as $var=>$value){

   $text = preg_replace("@\\$" . $var . "([^a-zA-Z_0-9\x7f-\xff]|$)@", $value . "\\1", $text);

}
```

Also you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

```
$allVars = get_defined_vars();
```

Answer (score 0):

[sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) is exactly for this purpose

```
$text = "Hello %s, how it's %s";
$name = "Joe";
$foo  = "going?";
$text = sprintf($text, $name, $foo);
```

Comment: I think it is not possible with your version. Because the variables in $text come from an input field and I want to use in freely the variables to use the space to fill it from my database. I hope you know what I mean :-)

Comment: Nope, I don't understand what do you mean.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a string replace. Because PHP will parse variables inside of strings, you can force it to not do that with a little trick:

```
$new_text = str_replace("$"."text1", $text1, $old_text);
```

Comment: I think he actually wants it to be replaced

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with $old_text?

My text in the variable $text look like this. Hi $text1, how are you? I hope you are fine. What do your dog $text2? Do you still have $text3?

What I must do if I have more than one variable to replace?

Comment: I used $new_text and $old_text so you could see that $old_text is the original text and $new_text is what you get after replacement. To do more replacements, you have to use str_replace again or do str_replace with arrays. However, I feel you are not up to using arrays if you are having difficulty reading the str_replace syntax. So, I suggest using multiple str_replace calls.